# Удаление вопросов автором после получения ответа

Tags: обсуждение

Буквально только что решил ответить на вопрос, написав достаточно (на мой взгляд) развернутое описание решения и причины возникновения, но в комментариях решение дали ранее на минуту, которое заключалось в простом изменения 1 на 2, в связи с чем автор вопроса просто его удалил.
С одной стороны его проблема решена, но с другой стороны SO вроде как не позиционируется как помощь одному человеку.
При этом мой ответ уже был опубликован, но удален вместе с родительским вопросом

Вопрос: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1466073/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/1466084#1466084)

Возможно стоит пересмотреть политику удаления вопросов?

---

Да, я не спорю, что данный вопрос не несет никакого вклада в сообщество и я не претендую на звание лучший отвечающий года, но если рассматривать это как прецедент, то многие отвечающие 10 раз подумают случись с ними подобная ситуация, когда ответ подготавливается более часа и после прочтения вопрос просто удаляется вместе со стараниями автора ответа.

---

UPD: Как минимальный вариант, возможность оставить заметку об авторе вопроса, которую видно только пользователю оставившему ее, что бы не попасться на эту "удочку" еще раз с одним и тем же человеком

Comment: возможно автор просто не увидел твой ответ. Если бы твой ответ кто-то успел бы плюсануть - то вопрос уже нельзя было бы так просто удалить

Comment: @Grundy, я действительно думаю что автор это не специально, не знал про механику с одним ответом нулевого рейтинга, спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Восстановить вопрос
2. Поставить плюс ответу (удалить можно только при единственном ответе с нулём)
3. Написать под вопросом коммент, чтобы больше так не делал

Comment: Спасибо! Не знал про то, что уже присутствует механика что вопрос, где есть ответ сложнее удалить. Буду более внимателен

Comment: Столкнулся с похожим, только ответ был принят... т.е. вопрос, у которого 1 ответ, ответ принят, но имеет рейтинг 0 так же можно удалить? [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1477573)

Comment: @SwaD, ответ не принят - вероятно, перед удалением он убрал галочку. Мне кажется, что с принятым ответом удалить нельзя, но я не уверен.

Comment: Спасибо. Просто в истории я вижу, что ответ принят и хлоп, удалено )