# Пока писал ответ, вопрос был удалён

Tags: обсуждение, ответы, удаление-вопросов, нытьё

Я нашёл один вопрос и решил на него ответить. Вопрос, конечно, не из идеальных, но всё-таки я начал писать на него ответ.

Вдруг я вижу сообщение "сообщение было удалено и недоступно для просмотра". Свой ответ я уже написал, и он получился довольно понятный, развёрнутый и **правильный**. К счастью, я успел скопировать текст ответа и текст ответа сейчас у меня на компьютере. Но опубликовать свой ответ я уже не могу, а время я на его написание потратил.

"Задать свой вопрос" и ответить на него не очень получиться, ведь я давал некоторые комментарии к коду автора. Что мне делать? [Вот страница с вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1496932/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-scanner-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4#).

Comment: `"Задать свой вопрос" и ответить на него не очень получиться, ведь я давал некоторые комментарии к коду автора.` - и что? Вы ведь задаёте **свой** вопрос, можете под свой ответ подкорректировать и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Понимаю тебя. Поэтому я часто достаю старые вопросы по любимым тегам (да-да, хочу значок `Некромант`) и начинаю на них отвечать. Галочку я скорее всего не получу (обычно участники давно уже не в сети), рейтинг скорее всего тоже (грустная статистика). За то не удалят раньше времени :)

Comment: Вам еще предстоит пройти такую штуку, как опубликовать ответ и не найти вопроса через 10 мин. Так же бывает, что народ принимает ответ и тут же удаляет вопрос. Иногда получается восстановить, но это если успели отследить... Так что да, бывает, и к этому надо относится спокойно. Если вопрос вам понравился и вы считаете, что он несет ценность сообществу, задайте его уже от своего имени и сами опубликуйте ответ. Если автор исходного вдруг "одумается", метите его вопрос как дубликат :)

Comment: @mironovmeow все у вас получится с получением данного достижения. Найти и ответить на один из бородатых вопросов не составляет труда, если конечно он актуален. А вот получить 5 голосов "за", вот здесь уже тяжелее

Comment: @SwaD  а разве можно удалить вопрос, если на него дали ответ?

Comment: @Зонтик Можно. Есть механизмы защиты. Нельзя удалить вопрос с 2-мя ответами или с ответом, за который отдали голос. Вроде как если есть комментарии под ответом.

Comment: Знакомая ситуация :)

Comment: @SwaD а вы писали (см. выше), что "Вам еще предстоит пройти такую штуку, как опубликовать ответ и не найти вопроса через 10 мин. Так же бывает, что народ принимает ответ и тут же удаляет вопрос. "

Comment: @Зонтик Да, писал, т.к. лично с этим неоднократно сталкивался. Смотришь, появилось +15, репа изменилась, лениво туда мышкой тыкаешь, а там ничего... А циферки изменились. Обновляем и циферки обратно уменьшились... [Вот тут даже немного жаловался](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12218/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0/12219#comment52922_12219) ))

Comment: @SwaD Описанное вами явление абсолютно обескураживает, когда с ним сталкиваешься впервые. Да тут создана весьма увлекательная система под стать любой популярной ролевой игре со своими бонусами и плюшками, можно следить за развитием своего персонажа. Но когда вопрошающий тупо удаляет свой вопрос после получения ответа со всеми результатами вашего труда после того как ими единолично воспользуется неприятно. Кстати с точки зрения авторского права это уже соавторство и согласно ГК РФ часть 4 в данном случае он утрачивает право самостоятельно распоряжаться его результатами.

Comment: @DmitryIvanov Я бы не стал сюда всякие ГК и УК приплетать. Это текущие реалии. Представьте, что будет задан вопрос, простой, обыденный, как обработать что то... Даёте ответ и бац, через пару месяцев ваш код всплывает в вирусе... Вы хотите быть соавтором этого? ) Надо понимать, что люди разные и по разному относятся к помощи. Кто то искренне благодарит, а кто то считает это вашими прямыми обязанностями. Для себя я уже понял, что давать ответ надо только в том случае, если видна заинтересованность и желание разобраться. Да, бывает всякое. Главное внутреннее удовлетворение от возможной помощи ))

Comment: SwaD я не приплетаю, констатирую факт. Знание это просто инструмент и как любой инструмент оно может быть использовано как во зло так и во благо и в этом нет вины автора, так что ваш довод мне не кажется убедительным. Более того я ни на чем не настаиваю и не вношу никаких предложений. Реалии так реалии.

Comment: @SwaD свежий [пример](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeIMG.png)...

Comment: @eccs0103 Ну это другое. Это удалили какого то участника со всеми его вопросами, ответами, галочкамии и голосами. Это другое!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Это стандартное и неприятное явление

Такое бывает иногда и тут некого винить. Выходов я вижу два:

1. Задать вопрос самому, дополнив описанием возможных проблем и решений которые были описаны в комментариях. И этот вариант я рекомендую.
2. Попросить автора восстановить вопрос и ответить на него, что работает далеко не всегда. Да и раз автор удалил, значит на то были причины и он вряд ли восстановит без резких убеждений.

Comment: Я бы к первому пункту добавил, что если вопрос был хорошим и уникальным(Ну т.е. не обыденным) или на который можно в последствии сослаться + он должен нести ценность.

Comment: @SwaD ну это само собой. Не подался в мелкие детали просто.

Comment: Ваше право, в то же время, мое мнение, что это важно учитывать, если публикуешь вопрос с целью самостоятельно на него ответить.

Comment: *Такое бывает иногда и тут некого винить.* Ну с формальной точки зрения можно было бы и поискать виноватого. Вопрос - это, конечно, собственность его автора.. но исключительно до момента публикации. Как только вопрос опубликован, он фактически передаётся автором в собственность сообщества. А потому наличие у автора права единолично принять и воплотить решение об удалении вопроса я всегда считал неправильным.

Comment: @Akina да, вопрос передается сообществу, но от имени автора. Сообщество решает судьбу этого вопроса, но не его связь  с автором. Поэтому, думаю, что автор имеет право "отвязать" от себя вопрос и пусть сообщество решит что с ним делать — тот же, что и удаление вопроса, а потом переспрашивание от имени другого участника, который согласен "взять" этот вопрос на себя. Конечно, было бы лучше если бы можно было изменить автора без удаления или же передать общему управлению, но раз такой функции нет...

Comment: @eccs0103 *автор имеет право "отвязать" от себя вопрос и пусть сообщество решит что с ним делать* Тут нет проблемы - это реализуется так же, как реализована отдача ответа сообществу. И как по мне, это должно происходит вместо удаления, и не должно требовать кучи телодвижений с восстановлением, поиском добровольца и протчая. Но этого делать никто ж не станет.. ну а то, что не всем удаление нравится - да перетопчутся. Впрочем, особо озабоченному автору никто не помешает в случае реализации вопрос сперва отвандалить, и лишь потом отвязать - снова телодвижения, но уже по откату.